# Environment variables not being resolved in Kubernetes Java deployment

Tags: java, kubernetes

After learning about arguments that can be passed to a Java 8 Virtual Machine to make it container-aware (i.e. -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap), I am trying to add these arguments to my Kubernetes deployment for a Spring Boot service.

In containers section of my deployment YAML file, I have the following:

```
    resources:
        requests:
            memory: "256Mi"
            cpu: "50m"
        limits:

            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
    env:
    - name: JVM_OPTS
      value: "-Xms256M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=1"
```

In my Dockerfile, I have:

```
    ENV JVM_OPTS="-Xmx256M"
    ENV JVM_ARGS="-Dspring.profiles.active=kubernetes"
    EXPOSE 8080
    ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JVM_ARGS $JVM_OPTS -jar testservice.jar" ]
```

I can't seem to figure out why the max heap sized does not get sized properly:

```
$ kubectl exec test-service-deployment-79c9d4bd54-trxgj -c test-service -- java -XshowSettings:vm -version'
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 875.00M
    Ergonomics Machine Class: server
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.8.0) (Alpine 8.171.11-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

On a local Docker install, I can see the JVM max heap set correctly:

```
$ docker run openjdk:8-jre-alpine java -Xms256M -Xmx512M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=1 -XshowSettings:vm -version
VM settings: 
    Min. Heap Size: 256.00M 
    Max. Heap Size: 512.00M 
    Ergonomics Machine Class: server 
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 

openjdk version "1.8.0_171" 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.8.0) (Alpine 8.171.11-r0) 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running `java -XshowSettings:vm -version` in container, `JVM_OPTS` is not include in your command.

Try with this one

```
kubectl exec test-service-deployment-79c9d4bd54-trxgj -c test-service \
          -- sh -c 'java $JVM_OPTS -XshowSettings:vm -version'
```

Comment: Thanks.  Added the missing $JVM_OPTS and see a property sized max heap now.

Comment: VM settings:
    Min. Heap Size: 256.00M
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 494.94M
    Ergonomics Machine Class: client
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.8.0) (Alpine 8.171.11-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the the specific case here is missing the `JVM_OPTS` in the startup command or startup script. However, more details on how to use these new options can be found in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52555036/2989261).

Comment: [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52556887/1059372)

Comment: Thanks for the insights!

Comment: np. Things are very subtle when dealing with a JVM process in a docker image on a k8s cluster, but very few actually take the time to reason about it

Answer (score 0):

While building your docker image from docker file your java env variables are resolved and passed to enterypoint and then the image is built with the resolved values. Which in your dockerfile are:

`JVM_OPTS="-Xmx256M"`

`JVM_ARGS="-Dspring.profiles.active=kubernetes"`

If you want to use kubernetes env variable for java arguments, then give entrypoint as some `script.sh`, and in `script.sh` you use env variables which will be resolved while running the image in kubernetes, instead of at build time.