# Does -Xms really disable XX:MaxRAMPercentage? Shouldn't it be -Xmx that disables XX:MaxRAMPercentage?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

According to [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/xxinitialrampercentage/) and [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/openj9/xxinitialrampercentage/index.html), if you specify `-Xms`, `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage` is ignored. Shouldn't it be

- if you specify `-Xmx`, `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage` is ignored
- and if you specify `-Xms`, `XX:InitialRAMPercentage` is ignored?

Quoted from both  [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/xxinitialrampercentage/) and [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/openj9/xxinitialrampercentage/index.html):

```
Note: If you set a value for -Xms, these options are ignored.
```

Notice: you might consider marking this at a duplicate of [Do java flags Xms and Xmx overwrite flag XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555036/do-java-flags-xms-and-xmx-overwrite-flag-xxusecgroupmemorylimitforheap) , but in that question they ask if Xmx overrides XX:MaxRAMPercentage respectively. Here I want to know if Xms overrides/disables XX:MaxRAMPercentage.

Comment: I just verified with OpenJDK 11 that the behavior of the HotSpot JVM is as you assumed. But that page is for OpenJ9, so perhaps they did it differently…

Comment: How did you verify with OpenJDK 11? You just passed the parameters and looked at how much virtual memory the jvm asked from the OS using top or ps?

Comment: Using `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` and checking the effective `InitialHeapSize` and `MaxHeapSize`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Holger's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714750/does-xms-really-disable-xxmaxrampercentage-shouldnt-it-be-xmx-that-disables/57773706#comment101872196_57714750) answers this question.

- @Holger tested openjdk 11, and observed `-Xms` had no affect on `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0`
- @joseph tested openjdk 8, and also observed `-Xms` had no affect on `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0`

Those Eclipse and IBM docs are incorrect.

Comment: I made this a community wiki because Holger's comment was the answer so I should not get the points for it.